# cURL results in NULL although JSON is valid

Tags: php, curl, null

I'm curling a url that drops a json result. The result of the curl is always NULL though.

main.php

```
function getUserSettings(){
...
$json = json_encode($userSettings);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
return $json;
}
```

getusersettings.php

```
...
$api->uid = isset($_SESSION['uid']) ? $_SESSION['uid'] : die();

$result = $api->getUserSettings();
echo $result;
...
```

settings.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {
    //get the user settings
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.url.com/api/getstgs');
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $obj = json_decode($result, true);
    print_r($obj);die();
}
...
generate html
...
?>
```

The json looks like this:

> {"lcns":[{"product_name":"Addon: Addonname","license_key_decrypted":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXX","expires_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"}],"stgs":[{"Type":"1","Amount":"0"}]}

Comment: Can you show what `$result` contains just after the `curl_exec()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the shown code, the cURL call is *expected* to 'fail'.

This is because cURL makes a *new request* which does not automatically include session information or cookies. Such behavior can be duplicated using cURL from the command-line or a browser tab *in a new incognito* window. (Checking the result of web requests from other tools can diagnose a number of issues much quicker than code changes.)

The following is expected to fail the request instead of returning the desired JSON unless the session "uid" value has previously been established *this* request. It does not matter if there is a session "uid" value in the request which invoked cURL: the request made by cURL is *separate*.

```
$api->uid = isset($_SESSION['uid']) ? $_SESSION['uid'] : die();
```